# Can JMS topic strings contain spaces in them?

Tags: jms, jms-topic

Can a JMS topic string contain space ? **EG: "/TOPIC STRING/"**
When i try to publish to this topic, it says it is an invalid destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS 1.1 specifications leaves "Topic String" (or Destination Address) syntax to JMS Providers. IBM MQ allows space in topic string. Please see here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q005000_.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But i still get the exception **nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedInvalidDestinationException: JMSCMQ0005: The destination name was not valid. The destination name specified does not conform to published destination syntax. Correct the specified destination name and try again.**

When i checked the stack trace and eventually the com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.0.1.3 - k701-103-100812.

I see the below code in com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.WMQDestinationURIParser.java:
`if( ... name.indexOf(" ") != -1)
{ throw JMSCMQ0005 exception}
}`

Comment: It worked when we used 7.5.0.0 versions of the com.ibm jars.